# how to get the latest updated value from the store while using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am currently using `redux toolkit` and the issue is that even though the value of an item added to the cart of a e-commerce web application is being updated to the redux store, when i try to use `useSelector` it does not find the value of the item added to the cart on the first click but when i do add the second item, I am able to grab both items from the redux store:

is there anything that i am missing to solve this issue? below is my current implementation.

```
cart.ts

export const cart = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateByPayload: (state, action: PayloadAction<Cart>) => {
      state = merge(state, action.payload);
    },
```

`merge` is from `lodash` `(https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge)`

Answer (score 1):

Writing `state = anything` in an Immer-powered reducer is always a bug, and won't work.  You have to either *mutate* the existing `state` object, or *return* a new value.

See the longer answer on this topic in our docs:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers